# Form not sending images to email

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I have a form that does not send the images to my email. On the form the user can upload two images and all the information submits to my email except the images do not.

This is the code for the form:

```
<div id="stylized" class="myform">
<form id="myform" name="myform" action="bookingform.php" method="post" >
<h1></h1>
<p></p>

<div id="firstname">
<label>Name
<span class="small">Add your name</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="FirstName" id="FirstName"  />
</div>

<div id="email">
<label>Email
<span class="small">Add a valid email address</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" />
</div>

<div id="phone">
<label>Tel Number
<span class="small">Add phone number</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="Phone" id="Phone" />
</div>


<label>Address
<span class="small">Add your address</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="Address" id="Address" />


<h2 style="margin-top:140px;">Event Venue Information</h2>

<div id="dates">
<label>Date of Event
<span class="small">Date of your occasion</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="datex" id="datex" />
</div>
<div>
<label>Occasion
<span class="small">Type of occasion</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="type" id="type" />
</div>

<div style="margin-left:315px;">
<label>Venue
<span class="small">Location of event</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="location" id="location" />
</div>
<div style="float:right; margin-right:25px;">
<label>Services Required
<span class="small">Service needed</span>
</label>
<textarea cols="40" rows="5" name="services">
</textarea>
</div>


<div style="margin-top:-20px;">
<label>Please photo's that you find are useful:</label>
<input type="file" name="image" size="40"
onchange="return validateFileExtension(this)">
<input type="file" name="image" size="40"
onchange="return validateFileExtension(this)">
</div>


<h2 style="margin-top:260px;">Additional Information</h2>

<div style="margin-left:-40px; margin-top:30px;">
<label>How you found us?
<span class="small">Website/DJ's/Friend</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="found" id="found" />
</div>

<div style="float:right; margin-right:10px;">
<label>Your comments/questions
<span class="small">Any other queries</span>
</label>
<textarea cols="40" rows="5" name="questions">
</textarea>
</div>
<div>
<input class="buttons" style="margin-top:10px; margin-left:110px;" type="submit" 
value="Submit" 
></input>
</div>

<div class="spacer"></div>

</form>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"
    xml:space="preserve">//<![CDATA[
//You should create the validator only after the definition of the HTML form
  var frmvalidator  = new Validator("myform");
  frmvalidator.addValidation("FirstName","req","Please enter your First Name");
  frmvalidator.addValidation("FirstName","maxlen=20",   "Max length for FirstName is 20");
  frmvalidator.addValidation("FirstName","alpha","Alphabetic chars only");



  frmvalidator.addValidation("Email","maxlen=50");
  frmvalidator.addValidation("Email","req");
  frmvalidator.addValidation("Email","email");

  frmvalidator.addValidation("Phone","maxlen=50");
  frmvalidator.addValidation("Phone","numeric");

  frmvalidator.addValidation("Address","maxlen=50");


//]]></script>
</div>
```

This is the php code:

```
<?php
$boundary = uniqid('np');

$field_name = $_POST['FirstName'];
$field_email = $_POST['Email'];
$field_phone = $_POST['Phone'];
$field_address = $_POST['Address'];
$field_date = $_POST['datex'];
$field_type = $_POST['type'];
$field_location = $_POST['location'];
$field_services = $_POST['services'];
$field_found = $_POST['found'];
$field_comments = $_POST['questions'];

$mail_to = 'user1@hotmail.co.uk';


$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Phone: '.$field_phone."\n";
$body_message .= 'Address: '.$field_address."\n";
$body_message .= 'Date: '.$field_date."\n";
$body_message .= 'Type of Occasion: '.$field_type."\n";
$body_message .= 'Location: '.$field_location."\n";
$body_message .= 'Services required: '.$field_services."\n";
$body_message .= 'How they found us: '.$field_found."\n";
$body_message .= 'Comments - Questions: '.$field_comments;

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers = 'From: '.$Email."\r\n";

 $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;boundary=" . $boundary . "\r\n";


$message = "This is a MIME encoded message."; 

 $message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
 $message .= "Content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";
 $message .= "This is the text/plain version.";

 $message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
 $message .= "Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";
 $message .= "This is the <b>text/html</b> version.";

 $message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "--";



$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
        window.location = 'http://www.google.co.uk';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to user1@hotmail.co.uk');
        window.location = 'url';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

I would be very grateful if someone could show me how to allow the images to send with the form.

Thanks

Edit:

I have tried to add this as a seperate script but it gives an error which keeps saying unexpected } this is the code:

```
//reads the name of the file the user submitted for uploading
    $image=$_FILES['image']['name'];
    //if it is not empty
    if ($image) 
    {
    //get the original name of the file from the clients machine
        $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    //get the extension of the file in a lower case format
        $extension = getExtension($filename);
        $extension = strtolower($extension);
    //if it is not a known extension, we will suppose it is an error and will not  upload the file,  
    //otherwise we will do more tests
 if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")) 
        {
        //print error message
            echo '<h1>Unknown extension!</h1>';
            $errors=1;
        }
        else
        {
//get the size of the image in bytes
 //$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] is the temporary filename of the file
 //in which the uploaded file was stored on the server
 $size=filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

//compare the size with the maxim size we defined and print error if bigger
if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)
{
    echo '<h1>You have exceeded the size limit!</h1>';
    $errors=1;
}

//we will give an unique name, for example the time in unix time format
$image_name=time().'.'.$extension;
//the new name will be containing the full path where will be stored (images folder)
$newname="images/".$image_name;
//we verify if the image has been uploaded, and print error instead
$copied = copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname);
if (!$copied) 
{
    echo '<h1>Copy unsuccessfull!</h1>';
    $errors=1;
}}}}

//If no errors registred, print the success message
 if(isset($_POST['Submit']) && !$errors) 
 {
    echo "<h1>File Uploaded Successfully! Try again!</h1>";
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you're even trying to include those images.  Are you handling the file uploads in a separate script?

Comment: @TheOx Sorry I have edited the above with a script that I am using as a seperate file.

Comment: In your file upload script you have an extra "}" in that line of 4 braces.  I'd suggest you format your code using indentation to make it easier to find those sorts of bugs.  Fix that and then see if your upload script works.

Answer (score 0):

You have not added enctype for form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myform" name="myform" action="bookingform.php" method="post" >
```

This might be a problem, hope it helps